# Scanf Y/N and Save for Future Use

Tags: c, char

I want to ask a specific question and get a Y/N answer read in by the user. I will need to use the character Y or N to change the outcome of the next question eventually, which is why I need the character to be saved so I can retrieve it later. I don't want to use a string or a for/while loop. Also, why do I need to include the * after "%c*"?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
int avgTemp, lowestTemp, temperature;
char choice ='Y';
char decision ='N';
printf("What is the average temperature?\n");
    scanf("%d", &avgTemp);

printf("What is the lowest temperature in last 24 hours?\n");
    scanf("%d", &lowestTemp);

printf("Has the temperature been over 99 degrees F for more than 30 minutes?
        Please answer Y for yes and N for no.\n");
    scanf("%c*", &choice);

printf("choice is %c", choice);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say saved to be retrieved later, do you mean persistence? You can write the character to a text file which can be read whenever your application needs to know the previous value.

Comment: Saved to be used later as in the final printf statement I just added. All it prints is "choice is" and I want it to print the letter of the choice, if I can do that?

Comment: That means you are saving the wrong character in `choice` - most likely, the Return you press right after entering a character. Try with a space instead of the `*` in that scanf.

Answer (score 3):

> Also, why do I need to include the * after "%c*"?

`%c*` means to scan for a character and then a `*` (which it will discard). Maybe you meant `%*c` which means do the scan but discard it. You don't need either of them.

`scanf` is a very problematic function and should be avoided. Your program illustrates the problem. `scanf` does not read a whole line. `scanf` will only scan stdin up to what you asked for *and then stop*. This means extra input and newlines can sometimes be left on the input stream for the next unsuspecting `scanf`. From the man page...

> Each successive pointer argument must correspond properly with each
>   successive conversion specifier (but see the * conversion below).  All
>   conversions are introduced by the % (percent sign) character.  The format string may also contain other characters.  White space (such as blanks, tabs, or newlines) in the format string match any
>   amount of white space, including none, in the input.  Everything else matches only
>   itself.  Scanning stops when an input character does not match such a format character.  Scanning also stops when an input conversion cannot be made (see below).

This makes it *very* easy to accidentally leave characters on the input buffer. Each of your `scanf("%d")` will read in the number and stop. This leaves a newline on the input buffer. This is fine for `%d` because...

> Before conversion begins, most conversions skip white space

...but not for `%c`.

> Matches a sequence of width count characters (default 1); the next pointer must be a pointer to char, and there must be enough room for all the characters (no terminating NUL is added).  ***The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed.  To skip white space first, use an explicit space in the format.***

So you need `scanf(" %c")` to make it work at all.

---

`scanf` is to be avoided because it's very, very vulnerable to unexpected input. Try giving "foo" to the first question. All the `scanf("%d")` will silently fail. And `scanf("%c")` will read `f`.

Instead, read the whole line with [`getline`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) (preferred as it handles memory allocation for you) or `fgets` and then use `sscanf` on the resulting string. This avoids all the above problems.

Comment: `"%c*"` means to scan a character and then attempt to scan the character `*`.  It does not mean "* means do the scan but discard it.".  It would have meant that with `"%*c"`

Comment: UV for the good discussion.  (although not a fan of `getline()` as it is vulnerable to resource exploit)

Comment: @chux Hmm, I never thought about that. Yeah, it would be nice if there was a way to set a max line limit. Well, better than the easily exploited buffer overflow with how people normally use `fgets`. What do you recommend instead?

Comment: 1) IMO there is no standard, nor semi-standard. So we are left to roll our own.  Something like `size_t getline_best(char **dest, size_t *size, size_t max, FILE *istream)` that returns the size read else with _somehow_ signaling `EOF`, `malloc` fail, `too_long_a_line` encountered, etc.  2) Unclear on `fgets()` exploit - did you mean `gets()`?